# How to run a background service in Oreo for longer period?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

Android Oreo has imposed many restrictions on running background service. Services now don't behave like normal in Oreo as they used to before.

But what if I have to run a service in background for long periods of time.

I am developing an application to launch the flashlight when user shakes the phone. To achieve this I will have to put the Sensor listener code inside a service.

How do I prevent android system to not kill the service.

PS: I don't want to start a foreground service with a notification.

Comment: If you're constantly running and constantly listening for sensor changes, the user should know about it (via a foreground service).

Comment: @ianhanniballake On the one hand, I appreciate that level of transparency.  On the other hand, the thing about Oreo as a user that makes me want to throw it in the trash is the number of useless notifications I can't get rid of due to foreground services that don't need to be foreground services.  I'd rather google had another tool for this, like a list of running services in settings, or a way to whitelist out apps I'm ok with like tasker.  I'd downgrade to Nougat in a second if I could.

Comment: @GabeSechan - assuming they're using notification channels, you can turn off the channel entirely (whether the displays doesn't affect the foreground behavior) or just lower it to minimum priority (so it doesn't display on the status bar).

Comment: @ianhanniballake I'd prefer them just to be gone.  THis change was a mistake by Google-  it makes to much cool functionality MUCH harder than it needs to be, clutters my notifications, and provides me no value as a user while reducing my options as a developer.  Services using battery was never a problem on my device, this change hasn't improved my battery life but has made my life difficult.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Does this work, can we programatically switch off a notification channel. And will it effect how system will treat foreground service?

Comment: @GurleenSethi - the app must post their foreground notification onto an `IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT` or higher channel to avoid 'App running in the background' notifications from the system. It would be up to users to adjust the priority after the fact.

Comment: There is got to be a way, there are applications out there doing this, For example 'TrueCaller' does this, they listen to when a call is initiated without showing a notification, and various other applications still do this. The question is how are they preventing system to kill the service.

Comment: @GurleenSethi: "For example 'TrueCaller' does this, they listen to when a call is initiated without showing a notification" -- there is [a broadcast `Intent` action](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL) for that, that they can register for in the manifest.

Comment: Note that targeting API 26 (and the background restrictions it entails) is mandatory [starting in late 2018](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html). What you see now (where apps may or may not be targeting API 26) is not indicative of what may be the case come the end of the year.

Comment: So there is just no way on Oreo that I can add this kind of functionality? Speaking of Explicit Broadcast, Google has also removed bunch of them.

Comment: @GurleenSethi: Google limited many implicit broadcasts, not explicit ones. A bunch of implicit broadcasts, including `ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`, [are documented as being whitelisted](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh snap, I meat to say 'implicit', typed 'explicit' by mistake.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you have any way to achieve this in Oreo?

Answer (score 11):

> How do I prevent android system to not kill the service.

To summarize the comments: Use a foreground service, with a notification on a dedicated channel, with the channel set to `IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT`. Advise the user that they can mute that channel (e.g., long-press on the `Notification` in the notification shade). Using a dedicated channel means that you can still raise notifications on other channels. Your notification should also be useful:

- Have a "stop" action to stop your service, if the user wants to shut it down for a while
- Tapping on the notification itself would lead to your activity for configuring your app's behavior

> I don't want to start a foreground service with a notification.

Then most likely you cannot write your app.

I cannot rule out the possibility of some bug in Android 8.x that could be exploited to have an indefinite-duration service. In fact, I'd consider it to be fairly likely that there's something floating around out there. However, this is clearly against Google intentions, meaning:

- Exploiting that technique, without what Google would consider to be valid justification, might get your app banned from the Play Store, if that was how you planned to distribute it
- The bug might be fixed in a future version of Android, and getting in an arms race with Google tends to be a losing proposition

There are enough "air gesture" apps floating about (i.e., do things based on a shake) that, ideally, Google would add some dedicated low-power API for it. For example, they could add functionality to `JobScheduler` to allow you to register for a shake event and have your `JobService` be invoked in that circumstance, just as they allow you to register for changes in a `ContentProvider`. I have no idea whether they will ever offer such an API, but you could file a feature request for it, if you wanted.

Comment: how i can create  a foreground service, with a notification on a dedicated channel, with the channel set to IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT?

Comment: @AniruddhParihar: That is well beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow comment. I suggest you ask 1+ separate Stack Overflow questions, where you explain exactly what you do not understand about [foreground services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground) and [notification channels](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels).

Comment: can you answer this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497436/how-to-run-background-service-for-instant-messaging-using-kurento-api-in-oreo

Comment: @CommonsWare How to start a service from a Broadcast receiver?

Comment: @Rahulrr2602: Call `startForegroundService()`, and ensure that the service itself calls `startForeground()` shortly after starting.

Comment: I tried calling `startForeground()` in `onStartCommand()` but it gives an error. Any idea what to do?

Comment: @Rahulrr2602: Ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve] and explain in detail what "gives an error" means.

Answer (score 6):

Make a service unstoppable on Oreo or later without shown notification is possible (Yes We Can).

Let me to explain how make a service stoppable ONLY BY USER and not by system (or better to say THE ONLY WAY TO STOP THEM IS UNINSTALLING YOUR APP).

Note that even I make a service unstoppable in my point of view is not a good technique and I’m CONTRARY on that for different reasons (like battery consuming, clear user experience etc.)

First of all you need to declare the service in manifest file.

The separate name “:serviceNonStoppable” make the service running in a separate process and not in main app process. Is better for background processes which need to run separately. 
To make our own service process invisible to other processes or apps you need to set exported=false parameter.
The description “@string/service_description” will say to users what your service do and why user should not stop them (you create this description in strings.xml).

```
  <service
      android:process=":serviceNonStoppable"
      android:name="your.package.name.serviceOn" 
      android:exported="false"
      android:description="@string/service_description" />
```

Secondly we go to create a support class with static methods usable in different points.

```
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class Utils {

   // This is a support class witch have static methods to use everywhere

   final static int NOTIFICATION_INT_CHANNEL_ID = 110211; // my daughter birthday but you can change that with your number
   final static String NOTIFICATION_STRING_CHANNEL_ID = "put.a.random.id.here"; //if you write "the.pen.is.on.the.table" is the same

   final static int TEST_THIS = 111; // or you can put here something else
   final static String BROADCAST_MSG_ID = "BROADCAST_MSG_ID"; // or you can put here something else
   final static String APP_MESSAGE = "your.package.name.action.APP_MESSAGE"; // or you can put here pippo.pluto.and.papperino

   static void returnUpMyService(final Context context) {
      try {
         //to avoid crashes when this method is called by service (from itself) make sure the service is not alredy running (maybe is in cache)
         if (killServiceIfRun(context)) {
            startServiceOn(context);
         }

      } finally {
         System.out.println(" I'm trying to start service ");
      }
   }


   private static boolean killServiceIfRun(final Context context) {

      boolean isRunning = isMyServiceRunning(context);
      if (!isRunning) { return true; }

      try {
         ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

         // maybe killing process is not terminated by system in this fase
         //I force to kill them by my one
         if (manager != null) {
            manager.killBackgroundProcesses(getServicename(context));
            return true;
         }
         return true;
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("killServiceIfRun error: " + e.toString());
      }

      return false;

   }


   private static boolean isServiceInCache(final Context context) {

      ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (manager != null && manager.getRunningAppProcesses() != null) {

         if (manager.getRunningAppProcesses().size() > 0) {
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo process : manager.getRunningAppProcesses()) {

               if (process.processName != null) {
                  if (process.processName.equalsIgnoreCase(getServicename(context))) {
                     // Here we know that the service is running but sleep brrrrrrrr
                     if (process.importance != ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_SERVICE) {
                        return true;
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }

      return false;
   }


   static void StartMyService(Context context) {

      // If the sevice is running doesn't need to restart
      if (isMyServiceRunning(context) && !isServiceInCache(context)) {
         return;
      }

      // If service is running but is in chache is the same like killed, so we need to kill them
      if (isServiceInCache(context)) {
         // this method at first kill and after that start the service
         returnUpMyService(context);

      } else {
         //Otherwise we start own service
         startServiceOn(context);
      }

   }


   private static void startServiceOn(final Context context) {
      // After we had been sure about that service doesn't exist
      // we make a schedule to restart them
      new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1).schedule(() -> {

         //Create an instance of serviceOn
         serviceOn service = new serviceOn();

         //prepare the launch intent
         Intent launchIntent = new Intent(context, service.getClass());

         // Now we start in background our service
         context.startForegroundService(launchIntent);

         // I put 50 ms to allow the system to take more time to execute GC on my killed service before
      }, 50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   }

   private static boolean isMyServiceRunning(final Context context) {

      ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (manager != null && manager.getRunningAppProcesses() != null) {

         if (manager.getRunningAppProcesses().size() > 0) {
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo process : manager.getRunningAppProcesses()) {
               if (process != null && process.processName != null && process.processName.equalsIgnoreCase(getServicename(context))) {
                  return true;
               }
            }
         }
      }

      return false;

   }


   static void SendMsgToService(Context context, int id, Map<String, Object> params) {

      try {
         Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(APP_MESSAGE);

         if (params != null) {

            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : params.entrySet()) {
               //System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());

               if (entry.getValue() instanceof String) {
                  mServiceIntent.putExtra(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
               } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof Integer) {
                  mServiceIntent.putExtra(entry.getKey(), (Integer) entry.getValue());
               } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof Float) {
                  mServiceIntent.putExtra(entry.getKey(), (Float) entry.getValue());
               } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof Double) {
                  mServiceIntent.putExtra(entry.getKey(), (Double) entry.getValue());
               } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof byte[]) {
                  mServiceIntent.putExtra(entry.getKey(), (byte[]) entry.getValue());

               }
            }
         }

         mServiceIntent.putExtra(BROADCAST_MSG_ID, id);
         context.sendBroadcast(mServiceIntent);

      } catch (RuntimeException e) {
         System.out.println(e.toString());
      }

   }


   private static String getServicename(final Context context) {
      //                                 the name declared in manifest you remember?
      return context.getPackageName() + ":serviceNonStoppable";
   }


}
```

This is service class witch extend IntentService.

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class serviceOn extends IntentService {

   // Needed to keep up notifying without show the icon
   private ScheduledExecutorService notifyer = null;


   // don't remove this. cause error becouse we declare this service in manifest
   public serviceOn() {
      super("put.a.constant.name.here");
   }


   // We need this class to capture messages from main activity
   private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

         if (intent != null) {
            if (intent.getAction() != null) {

               if (intent.getAction().equals(Utils.APP_MESSAGE)) {

                  int msgID = intent.getIntExtra(Utils.BROADCAST_MSG_ID, -1);

                  switch (msgID) {

                     case Utils.TEST_THIS:

                        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
                           System.out.println(message);
                        }
                        //Do your task here
                        //Do your task here
                        //Do your task here
                        //Do your task here
                        break;

                  }

               }
            }
         }
      }

   };


   @Override
   protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) { }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      return START_STICKY;
   }


   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();


      try {
         // First of all we need to register our receiver
         List<String> actions = Arrays.asList(
         Utils.APP_MESSAGE, // this is the string which identify our mesages
         Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON, // this event is raised on sreen ON by system
         Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF, // this event is raised on screen OFF by system
         Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);// this event is raised every minute by system (helpful for periodic tasks)

         for (String curIntFilter : actions) {
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(curIntFilter);
            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
         }
      } catch (RuntimeException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }


      final Notification notificationDefault = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), Utils.NOTIFICATION_STRING_CHANNEL_ID)
                                               .setOngoing(true) //Ongoing notifications do not have an 'X' close button, and are not affected  by the "Clear all" button
                                               .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE) // indicate this service is running in background
                                               .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_radio) // put here a drawable from your drawables library
                                               .setContentTitle("My Service")  // Put here a title for the notification view on the top

                                               // A smaller explanation witch system show to user this service is running
                                               // in background (if existing other services from other apps in background)
                                               .setContentText("My Service is unstoppable and need to run in background ")
                                               .build();


      // This is an efficient workaround to lie the system if we don't wont to show notification icon on top of the phone but a little aggressive 
      notifyer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
      notifyer.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {

         try {
            // Here start the notification witch system need to permit this service to run and take this on.
            // And we repeat that task every 15 seconds 
            startForeground(Utils.NOTIFICATION_INT_CHANNEL_ID, notificationDefault);

            //immediately after the system know about our service and permit this to run
            //at this point we remove that notification (note that is never shown before)
            stopForeground(true);

            //better not invoke Exception classes on error, make all a little heavy
         } finally {
            // Log here to tell you your code is called
            System.out.println(" Service is running");
         }

         // So, the first call is after 1000 millisec, and successively is called every 15 seconds for infinite
      }, 1000, 15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

   }


   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {

      // unregister the receiver
      unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

      // stop the notifyer
      if (notifyer != null) {
         notifyer.shutdownNow();
         notifyer = null;
         System.out.println(" notifyer.shutdownNow() ");
      }


      final Context context = getBaseContext();

      try {

         new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

               // The magic but dirty part
               // When the system detect inactivity by our service decides to put them in cache or kill it
               // Yes system you can kill me but I came up stronger than before
               Utils.returnUpMyService(context);
            }
         }.start();

      } finally {
         System.out.println("You stop me LOL ");
      }

   }


}
```

And here the usage.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

import java.util.HashMap;

class MyActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      // Sstart the first time
      Utils.StartMyService(this);

      // Test after 3 seconds
      new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
         Utils.SendMsgToService(X_App.getContext(), Utils.TEST_THIS, new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("message", "Hello from main activity");
         }});
      }, 3000);



   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, appreciate it. PS: No longer do android dev, moved to Flutter :)

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj, good answer and also good approach. Thank you very much.

Comment: Seems a little bit a fox way like but run perfectly  ;) Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @G3nt_M3caj ! This is an impeccable solution!

Comment: @vidulaJ , It’s not a battery-friendly solution, but, works fine. You are welcome :)

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj Of course, but this works fine! Wonder whether this will be accepted at the review process in Google Play.

Comment: @vidulaJ I have 2 app which needs to have unstoppable service on GP. Have fun :)

Answer (score 3):

I discovered that we can run forground  service without  showing notification  for android  oreo and above, here is the solution   first create   notification  with  notification  Channel  also set channel id for notifications   then   start forground service with notification.  now it's time to cancel notification Channel with id  after 1 or 2 second  that's means the notification will remove  and the service  will run alwayes  . that's all

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able to run background services long running in Oreo as there are behaviour changes, now Oreo to optimise system memory, battery etc, it kills background service, to solve your issue you should use foreground service.

Have a look at **Background execution limits** 
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes

Hope this helps in understanding the issue....