# Android Background Service for Message Receiving

Tags: android, firebase, xmpp, android-service, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have set up a XMPP server and made a client app using smack on android, everything worked fine but I'm testing the app on newer phones and it's not working anymore.

Android kills the service that was waiting for messages (kills the service when the user closes the app), I've been reading and people says that I should use FCM but I want to use my own message server because I added some special logic to the user administration on the XMPP server. I don't know if I can use the FCM sdk to recieve my own messages and running the code from there.

If I have no choice but to use FCM that seems bad to me and auto imposed, that would make use my DB for storing the tokens (which cost me money) and I would have to make a lot of code on my server to handle the logic of the tokens on top of the logic of the current user administration.

Answer (score 0):

Oreo (Android 8) came with limitations to background services, so that is probably why your service gets killed. See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html

In order to keep your service alive you could try something like this: [How to run a background service in Oreo for longer period?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996560/how-to-run-a-background-service-in-oreo-for-longer-period)