# Keep service alive in Android Oreo like whatapp

Tags: android, websocket, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo

How does wechat or whatapp show notification when receiving new message immediately?
If background is killed , it can't do anything in background doesn't it?
In most of country, we can use FCM.
If user is in china, how to make the service still alive and receive data in background without FCM?﻿

My company is using websocket in our Web.
How can I still keep websocket connected in background service without FCM?

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996560/how-to-run-a-background-service-in-oreo-for-longer-period you have to go for JobScheduler i guess