# How to run background service for Instant Messaging using Kurento API in Oreo?

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-8.0-oreo, kurento

Android Oreo has released with many restrictions on running background services/Task. Services now don't behave like normal in Oreo as they used to before.

But what if I have to run a service in background for 24*7 for Instant Messaging.

I am developing an application for Instant messaging using [kurento Third Party API](https://www.kurento.org/whats-kurento). To achieve this I will have to run a background service which communicate with server for new messages.

Lower then Oreo its working fine.

How do I prevent android system to not kill the service?.

I don't want to show a notification all time while my service is running because i will run my service for 24*7 for new messages so it feels cheap UI Experience to user.

Comment: "I don't want to show a notification all time while my service is running" -- then you will not be able to write your app, most likely.

Answer (score 0):

After Nougat version the way back ground service is changed. If you want your background service to work, you can do as mentioned in the code below. In IntentService, the life cycle method **onCreate()** is called. And in this method add below code.

```
  @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    int NOTIFICATION_ID = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis()%10000);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, new Notification.Builder(this).build());
    }

}
```

And when you are calling service, call your service via blow code

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, FindNumberService.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        context.startForegroundService(intent);
    }
    else {
        context.startService(intent);
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i have tried it, its not working, Oreo stop the service when its in doze mode.

Answer (score 0):

As the way to do, you should modify logic of incoming signals to use as channel for incoming messages push notifications. When app goes to background, you have to rely on [push notifications with high priority.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message)

And after got push, you can carry out all needed stuff.

Comment: i didn't understand your logic can you explain more on details. I have implemented   instant messaging and group chat both in this app.. group chat it based on room creation.

Comment: 1. On the moment when server emits events to user (about new message, or some other room states changes, etc) via websocket, just send it events via 'push notifications' as well. Clients, even being in 'doze mode' are possible getting such FSM messages. By obtaining such 'push', perform all needed logic (open chat page, show notification, etc)

Comment: Actually kurento is using web-socket internally, to communicate with server it got connected first time and then it continuously firing his event for particular, and we perform operations according to event, either we have to create notification or show in chat window. so my question id how i can integrate FCM for this.

Comment: For that I need to view more details, how exactly do you use kurento service, which modules, signaling api etc. Look through to the Kurento arch
http://www.kurento.org/kurento-architecture
and Kurento App Server documentation.
https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.6.2/mastering/kurento_API.html
If you cannot do it by Kurrento APIs you always are possible to modify Kurento server code for your needs