# Service not re-started

Tags: android, service

We have stumbled upon an issue in Android 8.1 and above that, we haven't seen before, and that, unfortunately, makes our app less convenient for our users. Background sticky services in Android 8.1 and above isn't re-started when user swipe kills the app.

In Android 8.0 and below, there are high promises for services to be always available in the background, especially for services that are implemented as "sticky services".

To sum it up, the non-sticky services is not re-launched during a swipe kill in the recent app list. For sticky services (application host together with the service), the app is re-launched shortly after the kill. And foreground services apps are actually never killed, even during a swipe kill.

This works as intended and just fine in Android 8.0 and before. So, after a kill swipe, the app process is re-created within a short time, and then onCreate and onStartCommand is called, starting up the service completely again.

But from Android 8.1, the onStartCommand call is omitted. So instead of getting onCreate and OnStartCommand, we get onCreate and OnDestroy. This effectively does not make the service active again. Needless to say, we cannot manually start our own service in `onCreate` either.

I think the following [article](https://medium.com/@er.abhishek.luthra/what-exactly-happens-to-running-services-when-you-swipe-an-android-app-from-recent-app-list-d343ca03a2a) shows the differences quite clear (and with functional code) between non-sticky services, sticky services, and foreground services.

In Android 8.1 and above, the onStartCommand call is omitted (and therefore the service is not restarted). So instead of getting onCreate and OnStartCommand, we get onCreate and OnDestroy during app re-creation.

Also, we would not prefer to have a visible app icon at the top persistent all the time (as when using setForeground service), and rather just let it work in the background without bothering the user too much.

Answer (score 1):

Don't Optimise Battery  may work your service to run properly 
you can also use AlarmManager to restart service after a fixed time

it could help [click](https://hashedin.com/blog/save-your-android-service-from-doze-mode/)

Comment: Thanks. I tried out your suggestion about "Don't Optimise Battery", and this setting does indeed affect the service behaviour. When enabled, the service is re-started as intended. However, as the default is to optimise the battery, every user will manually need to go into Settings - Battery and disable it (if they want), I guess not a single "normal" user would do this. We want an automatic solution to this, so I will have check into at your other solution with AlarmManager in more detail. I tested it last week, and couldn't get it to work, though.

Comment: I just tested your suggestion with AlarmManager. It did work with battery optimisation disabled, although this is actually not necessary, since the service is re-started quite fine. So the service is now restarting fine twice However, with battery optimisation enabled (default), AlarmManager will not work

Comment: may be you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996560/how-to-run-a-background-service-in-oreo-for-longer-period

Comment: in oreo and above android banned the service to run indefinite for battery optimization that's why service are not running in background for long time its because they Introduced DOZE MODE in Oreo which is why you hv to check my above solutions good luck

Comment: Thanks for the link. To sum up, from what I could understand from the link, your only valid option is to mark your service as a foreground service. Even if you find a way to let it execute as a background service for an infinite amount of time, chances are that you app could be band from Google Play (because that was not their's intention  of using public API's), or that it is likely to stop working in future platform versions. Would that be a summary to it?

Comment: Well, both resistent from kill swipe and running for infinite amount of time, are the requirements to make the app convenient for our users. (Our app tries to connect to specific BLE-devices in the background and stream data from them.)

Answer (score 0):

from android 8 shouldn't be started service in background, you must start service as foreground.

my suggestion using android workManager supported by Google [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

workManager is a stable and reliable library for working with service and schedulers task

Comment: Thanks for the tip. For the moment, I think we would just go with using a foreground service instead of a background service. It seems to work just fine, at least speaking about strict functionality. We might try WorkManager in the future. But we have strict requirement to always be able to connect to an available Bluetooth-device in the background (quite quickly) and begin to stream data from it. Would you think a WorkManager is a viable solution for this? From what I've read, the short answer is "possibly", but I am not convinced.

Comment: workmanager is suitable for working background task or scheduler, but I'm not implemented bluetooth stream data in background. if we suppose this like downloading or uploading a file with internet it's possible.